# R: run time issue, loop, two large dataframes, efficiency

Tags: r

I am working on some mass transportation analysis. I have two large dataframes, df:"links" and df:"incl_1stop". The first contains the raw data, 100000 obs - all existing one directional station-station (A to B) links/edges incl. arrival and departure times. The second contains all possible "one stop-transfer" combinations (meaning A via B to C), which I created with a loop.

I would now like to create all possible "two-stop-combinations" by linking A-B-C of df:"incl_1stop" with all "suitable" obs in df:"link" conditionally on C in df:"incl_1stop" == A in df:"link" and some other constraints (see below).

I tried the following loop:

```
two_stop <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
mtt <-5
total_travel_time <- 240

for(i in 1:length(incl_1stop$ID)){#all one stop paths
  for(j in 1:length(links$ID)){#all existing direct links
   if(incl_1stop$dest[i]==links$orig[j] & !is.na(incl_1stop$dest[i]) &!is.na(links$orig[j])){#destination one-stop path = origin link
    if((links$dep_minute[j] - incl_1stop$arr_minute[i]) >= mtt & !is.na(links$dep_minute[j]) &!is.na(incl_1stop$arr_minute[i])){#minimum transit time 
     if((links$arr_minute[j] - incl_1stop$dep_minute[i]) <= total_travel_time & !is.na(links$arr_minute[j]) &!is.na(incl_1stop$dep_minute[i])){#max travel time
      if(links$dest[j]!=incl_1stop$orig[i]& !is.na(links$dest[j])& !is.na(incl_1stop$orig[i])){#loop first origin
       if(links$dest[j]!=incl_1stop$dest[i]& !is.na(links$dest[j])& !is.na(incl_1stop$dest[i])){#loop second origin

          two_stop[k,1]<-incl_1stop$orig[i]#first node/origin
          two_stop[k,2]<-incl_1stop$dest[i]#second node
          two_stop[k,3]<-incl_1stop$dest2[i]#thrird node
          two_stop[k,4]<-incl_1stop$dep_minute[i]#depature time first node
          two_stop[k,5]<-incl_1stop$arr_minute2[i]#arrival time endpoint third node
          two_stop[k,6]<-incl_1stop_$prov2[i]#provider last path element

          two_stop[k,7]<-incl_1stop$ID1[i]#ID first edge
          two_stop[k,8]<-incl_1stop$ID2[i]#ID second edge

          two_stop[k,9]<-links$ID3[j]#ID additional/third edge
          two_stop[k,10]<-links$dep_minute[j]#depature time third element
          two_stop[k,11]<-links$dest[j]#destination third element/fourth node
          two_stop[k,12]<-paste0(incl_1stop$path[i],"_",links$dest[j]) #travel path
          two_stop[k,13]<-(links$arr_minute[j]-incl_1stop$dep_minute[i])#total travel time first node-fourth node
          k <- k+1 
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
}
}
```

This loop however needs literally days to go through the frames and generate results. I assume that the code is not very efficient.
Do you have recommendations of how to significantly speed up the procedure?

Comment: You should use the igraph package.

Comment: we are currently testing this option- thanks. considering the temporal nature of the graph and the additional constraints in place, we are not sure that this yields significant gains.     Any other idea how to speed up the given loop?